# how to use ajax in jQuery in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to post javascript variable to another php file and I search using Ajax may help.I want to get back the data on another php file by "post" method.But I can't use $.ajax({}) directly inside javascript:

```
function input() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'update_service.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            name: name,

        },
        success : function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

The error message said "unexpected function ajax()". How to fix it?

Comment: You miss a } in your code snippet, did you import jQuery Ajax in your page head?

Comment: how to import jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Version

```
$.post( "update_service.php", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Comment: Are you able to post data to server ? Can u check it ? Check your logs, console or db. Also, Can you share your back-end function too that accepts POST method.